# C# Verify if certificate was signed by known intermediate authority

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

I'd like to know if it's possible to verify that a specific certificate was signed by a known intermediate authority.

My actual code test if all the chain is correct, but doesn't work if the self signed CA root is not added to the chain

```cs
public static bool IsLeaf(this X509Certificate2 leaf, X509Certificate2 root, params X509Certificate2[] intermediates)
{
    var chain = new X509Chain(false);

    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;
    
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Clear();
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(root);
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.AddRange(intermediates);

    var isChainFull = chain.Build(leaf);

    return isChainFull;
}
```

My unit tests

```cs
var root = X509CertificateHelper.CreateRoot("cm", "ou", "o", "l", "s");

var intermediate = root.CreateIntermediate("cm1", "ou", "o", "l", "s");

var leaf = intermediate.CreateLeaf("cm2", "ou", "o", "l", "s");

Assert.True(leaf.IsLeaf(root, intermediate));
Assert.True(leaf.IsLeaf(intermediate)); // this one fail
```

Comment: actually, it does work and pass this test as well. Your intermediate certificate was not signed by a known/trusted authority. And this matches your `verify that a specific certificate was signed by a known intermediate authority` intention. What is your question then?

Comment: It's currently not working https://github.com/Dative-GPI/bones/runs/7455160104?check_suite_focus=true#step:6:186 and when i'm talking about known intermediate, it's not a trusted intermediate, it's custom one but I create it so I know it. Not sure if it's clear.

Comment: your unit test is incorrect, for `leaf.IsLeaf(intermediate)` call with your examples, the proper assertion must be `Assert.False`.

Comment: `I create it so I know it` the code cannot magically figure out what you know or don't. Chaining engine determines that extra certificate should exist in chain, but can't locate it and fails.

Comment: I'll give you more context, I have a chain of 4 intermediates root before my leaf. And I don't want to add all the intermediates and the root to the chain to test if my leaf was signed by my pki. I just want to know if the leaf was signed by the last intermediate that I have in-memory ant that's why I want the assertion to be true because my leaf certificat is a leaf of my intermediate certificate, even if I the chain is not complete

Comment: @Crypt32 OP is passing just `intermediate` to the function as the parameter for `root` and no `params intermediates` certificates. `root` in the function is then the only certificate added to `CustomTrustStore` as a trusted root, so it shouldn't make a difference if its root is not trusted because it is a root itself.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you do not have a complete understanding on how certificate chaining engine works.

1. certificate chaining engine is system function, so it has no knowledge what data or certificates your application stores (whether in memory or anywhere else). If you want to let CCE to be aware of them, you have to explicitly pass them to `X509Chain` instance via `ExtraStore` and/or `CustomTrustStore` properties of [X509ChainPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainpolicy) object.
2. `X509Chain` does not support non-root anchoring. That is, `CustomTrustStore` collection must store only roots (self-signed CA certs). Non-root certificates are not used to establish a trust.

If your goal is to determine if your leaf certificate was signed by particular issuer, then you should modify the code:

replace:

```
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;
```

with:

```
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
```

replace:

```
chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.AddRange(intermediates);
```

with:

```
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(intermediates);
```

replace:

```
var isChainFull = chain.Build(leaf);
```

with the code which reads value from `chain.build(leaf)` and that `chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate` is the same certificate as expected signer.

Comment: Is there no way to verify against an intermediate CA when the root is not trusted? It would seem like a common necessity, for example when verifying EAP-TLS certificates you might only want certificates chained from a particular CA, regardless of whether its root is trusted.